# Two different C programs are accessing a file

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I have an application on Linux platform which requires a server program to write data to a bin file continuously. At the same time another program needs to read the written values. Should I be concerned if I am not locking the file during the read and the write process?

Comment: What kind of application, what kind of data, what is the binary file, what is the bandwidth?

Comment: If the reading process can identify message boundaries and continue reading when it has an incomplete message, then there isn't a huge problem with no locking.  If the reading process isn't equipped to repeatedly read past the end of file, then you'll have problems.  So, the most critical point is 'does the writer write messages that have a clear end for each message'?  (A clear end might be a newline, for example; or you might be using a TLV — type, length, value — format; or you might have end markers for a message, or ...)

Answer (score 2):

You should be concerned. I assume you are sure that no other program (than the two executables mentioned in your question) are accessing that file. You should indeed lock to serialize that access. Use [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html), or [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html) which uses [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)

BTW, is the file read and written sequentially? Did you consider using some higher-level thing, e.g. [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/manual/html_node/) or some database like [mariadb](https://mariadb.org/) or [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/) or [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/), etc...

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on what your requirements are? Can you modify the server process? If so, you have endless possiblities. This is a well studied problem, Interprocess Communication, [wikipedia IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Otherwise, in my own test program, it seemed that no locking was necessary to have a producer and consumer operating on the same file. This is anecdotal evidence only, I make no guarantees.

Producer:

```
int main() {
    int fd = open("file", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);

    const char * str = "str";
    const int str_len = strlen(str);
    int sum = 0;
    while (1) {
        sum += write(fd, str, str_len);
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Consumer:

```
int main() {
    int fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);

    char buf[10];
    const int buf_size = sizeof(buf);
    int sum = 0;
    while (1) {
        sum += read(fd, buf, buf_size); 
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

(Includes:)
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

This program assumes the "file" exists already.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what has already been said here, check your OS documentation.  In principle there should not be problem when reading, if reading is atomic (I.e no task switch during the operation), should be ok. Also the OS could have its own restrictions and locks, so be careful.